# Weird bug with rendering components in React app

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

Our react app for a school project is having an unusual bug with our css when a warning dialog appears on the screen. When the warning pops up on the Resource side, it looks fine. But when the  warning pops on the Event side, the Resource board isn't greyed out. Here is how the index.js looks:

```
import React from "react";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import ResourceBoard from "./components/resources/ResourceBoard";
import EventBoard from "./components/events/EventBoard";
import "./index.css";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container);

function toggleBackgroundImage() {
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  if (body.classList.contains("body2")) {
    body.classList.remove("body2");
  } else {
    body.classList.add("body2");
  }
}

root.render(
    <div>
      <div>
        <button className="home-btn">Home</button>
        <button className="save-btn">Save Board</button>
        <button className="dark-mode-button" onClick={toggleBackgroundImage}>
          Light/Dark mode
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
      <EventBoard />
      <ResourceBoard />
      </div>
    </div>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

And here is the code for the warning dialog for when an event is deleted

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import EventCard from "./EventCard";
import "./event.css";

export default function DeleteEventPopUp(props) {
  const url = "https://localhost:7282/api/AllResources/events";
  let newEvent = {
    id: "",
    title: "",
    description: "",
    days: "",
    startTime: "",
    endTime: "",
    eventType: "",
    deleted: "",
  };
  function deleteEvent(updatedResource) {
    fetch(`${url}/${updatedResource.id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedResource),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
        } else {
          console.log(`Error updating resource: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error updating resource: ${error.message}`);
      });
  }

  //finds title to display on window when clicked, works as of 2/22 at 1:11 PM
  for (let i = 0; i < props.allEvents.length; i++) {
    const oldEvent = props.allEvents[i];
    if (oldEvent.id === props.currentEventId) {
      newEvent = {
        id: oldEvent.id,
        title: oldEvent.title,
        description: oldEvent.description,
        days: oldEvent.days,
        startTime: oldEvent.startTime,
        endTime: oldEvent.endTime,
        eventType: oldEvent.eventType,
        deleted: true,
      };
    }
  }
  function handleYes() {
    deleteCard();
    deleteEvent(newEvent);
    props.setDeletePop(false); // make pop up go away
  }

  //this used to live in resource card before pop up, now lives here :)
  function deleteCard() {
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < props.allEvents.length; i++) {
      const oldEvent = props.allEvents[i];
      if (oldEvent.id === props.currentEventId) {
        newArray.unshift({ ...oldEvent, deleted: true });
      } else {
        newArray.push(oldEvent);
      }
    }
    console.log(newArray);
    props.setAllEvents(newArray);
  }

  // does it's job by making modal disappear
  function handleNo() {
    props.setDeletePop(false);
  }

  // below is the actual html for the delete pop up
  return (
    <div>
      {props.showDeletePop && (
        <div
          style={{
            background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
            opacity: "0.1",
            position: "fixed",
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            zIndex: 999,
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              background: "white",
              padding: "20px",
              borderRadius: "10px",
              textAlign: "center",
            }}
          >
            <h1>WARNING</h1>
            <h3>You are about to delete the following event: {newEvent.title}</h3>
            <h3>Are you sure you want to do this?</h3>

            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                marginTop: "10px",
              }}
            >
              <button onClick={handleYes}>Yes</button>
              <button onClick={handleNo}>No</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's what the board looks like by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hij13.jpg)

[Here's what the resource delete looks like, and what event delete should look like visually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKh6U.png)

[Here is what the event delete looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh5bA.png)

All of the pop up windows work as intended, but the visual bug between resource and event is the issue

We've tried rendering the different boards in various orders, but the way it is now in index.js seems to work the best.

Comment: You haven't included the relevant code that would allow us to help -- where is the warning dialog? what does its HTML look like? Where in the DOM does it get injected, relative to your EventBoard and ResourceBoard? -- but it looks likely to be a z-index or stacking-context issue; the HTML for the dimmed-background part of the dialog box is stacked behind the EventBoard component's HTML.

Comment: (Possibly this is because each of your Boards is injecting its own copy of the warning dialog inside itself, and the ResourceBoard is stacked behind the EventBoard.  If that's the case, you could inject the warning dialog in the DOM root alongside the boards, at the desired stacking level, and have the boards hide/reveal it instead of containing their own copy.  Or you might be able to fix it by just fiddling with z-index values. I'm having to guess, because you've not included the information necessary to give you a real answer.)

Comment: Please include the code for the other components as well.

Often a sitewide dialog will be included in the root component, and each component could hide/show it conditionally. For example, see the layout for react-toastify: https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/installation